# How can I iterate through a DataFrame to concatenate strings once an empty cell is reached?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-camelot

I've extracted some pdf tables using Camelot.
The first column contains merged cells, which is often problematic.

Despite tweaking some of the advanced configurations, the merged cells for the first column, span across rows.

I'd like to iterate through the first column rows to achieve the following:

1. Start from the top
2. if you find an empty cell, then move / concatenate each previous string sequentially (with a space in between), to the first instance of a non-empty cell.

| Column | What I have now | What I'd like |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A B C D |
| 2 | B |  |
| 3 | C |  |
| 4 | D |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 | F | F G |
| 7 | G |  |
| 8 |  |  |

Comment: empty cell means NaN?

Comment: Do you want to keep the newly empty rows, or drop those rows? Should there be 8 or 2 rows in the final result?

Comment: What is your expected output? If only 2 rows, what should be in `Column`?

Comment: @PandaKim no, they're empty cells. Gaberocksall / Nick I'd like to keep the rows, as they contain useful data in columns 2 onwards.

Comment: @NoExpert What do you mean by "empty cell" but not "NaN"? Please clarify. It would be helpful to provide input in code.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
cond1 = df['What I have now'].isna()
g = df['What I have now'].groupby(cond1.cumsum()[~cond1])
m = g.cumcount().eq(0)
df["What I'd like"] = g.transform(' '.join).where(m)
```

df:

```
   Column What I have now What I'd like
0       1               A       A B C D
1       2               B           NaN
2       3               C           NaN
3       4               D           NaN
4       5             NaN           NaN
5       6               F           F G
6       7               G           NaN
7       8             NaN           NaN
```

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Column': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
         'What I have now': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', float('nan'), 'F', 'G', float('nan')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```